# Is there a way to protect the entire worksheet but allow autofilter?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, autofilter

I've been trying to solve this one for a while now, but I just could not figure out what to do.

I have a dataset which I've edited and saved as an Excel file using xlsxwriter. The worksheet must be protected by passowrd, but the autofilter at the header must be usable.

So far I have managed to either protect the worksheet as a whole, headers included, or unprotect the header only, but with an unusable autofilter.

This is what I have so far:

[image]

Whenever I click any of the worksheet's cells, the protected message appears, as expected, but I can't seem to click the autofilters.

Also, after unprotecting the worksheet and trying to protect it manually, I've discovered the 'Use Autofilter' option is not selected by default, while 'Select locked cells' and 'Selec unlocked cells' are selected:

[image]

After selecting 'Use Autofilter' option and protecting the worksheet, I got a working autofilter:
[image]

Is there a way to set this 'Use Autofilter' option to True using xlsxwriter? If not, how can I adjust code to implement it? Here is the code snippet:

```
# Loading input (.csv) information into a dataframe
csv_dataframe = pd.read_csv(report_csv_file, sep = ',', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine = 'python', index_col = None, names = ['TIPO', 'CODIGO', 'DESCRICAO',
'FORNECEDOR', 'PRINCIPIO_ATIVO', 'ANVISA', 'FABRICANTE'])

# Resetting Pandas formatting before creating a new excel file
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None

# Creating a writer object
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(template_excel_file, engine = 'xlsxwriter')

# Converting dataframe to Excel
excel_dataframe = csv_dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Material Alto Custo', index = False, header = ['TIPO', 'CODIGO', 'DESCRICAO',
'FORNECEDOR', 'PRINCIPIO_ATIVO', 'ANVISA', 'FABRICANTE'])

# Obtaining dataframe dimensions
(max_row, max_col) = csv_dataframe.shape

# Initiallizing workbook/worksheet
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Material Alto Custo']

# Header formatting
header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold' : True, 
'font' : 'Arial', 
'size' : 10,
'border' : 1})

# Column formatting
font_size_and_border = workbook.add_format({'font' : 'Arial', 'size' : 10, 'border' : 1, 'align' : 'left'})
column_left_zeroes_format_and_border = workbook.add_format({'num_format' : '00000000','font' : 'Arial', 'size' : 10,  'border' : 1, 'align' : 'left'})

# Applying specific formatting to columns
worksheet.set_column(0,max_col - 1, 20.0, font_size_and_border)

# Applying specific formatting to columns
worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 20.0, column_left_zeroes_format_and_border)

# Rewriting header and applying header formatting after column formatting
for col_num, value in enumerate(csv_dataframe.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

# Applying autofilter to header
worksheet.autofilter(0, 0, 0, 6)

# Protecting worksheet with password
worksheet.protect('enterPasswordHere')
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: worksheet.protect('enterPasswordHere', {'autofilter': True}) should do the trick according to the documentation: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#protect